# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class SwitchPreference

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to read my app preferences and I get this error:

Settings activity:

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        try
        {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("errorSettings", Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
        }
    }
}
```

Preferences XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="General">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:title="Downloader"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="useDownloader"
        android:summary="Enable to use" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

and on the application manifest I set this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

and the first error I get is:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class SwitchPreference
```

Thanx upfront.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SwitchPreference` was added in API Level 14. You cannot use it on earlier versions of Android. Since you are trying to support back to API Level 9, you can either:

1. Use different preference XML for earlier versions, using a `CheckBoxPreference` instead of a `SwitchPreference`, or
2. Just use `CheckBoxPreference` and drop `SwitchPreference` for now